# Azure DevOps Pipelines Release Copy Files step "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps pipelines releases to try to deploy a windows service on premise. Periodically, the windows copy files step will hang and try again every 30 seconds and output "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" as it attempts to copy the build artifacts.

We've ruled out any kind of permission issue. We've tried all sorts of tools to see what might be locking these files up and they don't tell us much.

This has happened before in the past with some other projects I was also trying to release on premise. *Sometimes*, I am able to just wait an hour or two and redeploy successfully (not exactly a solution I'm satisfied with), but this one particular project, a windows service, seems to be experiencing the issue very, very frequently. Almost every time I try to deploy.

Has anyone else experienced this? Or any word from Microsoft on the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your process before and after copying files? Are you stopping the service first?

Comment: Hi Dan. We are stopping the service. The entire process is essentially stop service, replace artifacts, start service. I actually don't know if that would make a difference or not. It's supposedly having trouble copying the files from our build server, not writing to the deployment server.

Comment: Here is a copied output, with some of my organization's information modified (it's not relevant anyways):

2019-11-18T13:25:13.3676815Z Waiting 30 seconds... Retrying...
2019-11-18T13:25:13.3768897Z      Newer         221696 SomePackage.dll
2019-11-18T13:25:13.3770595Z 2019/11/18 07:25:13 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying File C:\Build\AzureOpsx64\Folder\bin\Release\SomePackage.dll
2019-11-18T13:25:13.3771461Z The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Do you use msbuild task in your pipeline?  Maybe you meet [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/783808/visual-studio-build-11510-the-process-cannot-acces.html) here?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue while trying to create and deploy a release from an existing artifact. So I have a build pipeline on Azure Devops that generates artifacts to be used by the release pipeline. All I did was to make a commit that triggered the build pipeline which generated a new artifact and triggered the release and it worked fine.

It was the first time I experienced this and I had no clue on why it happened.

I'm going to be doing more research and share any thing I find helpful.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was?